# How to create a site map diagram for existing SharePoint 2010 intranet sites?

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-server, architecture, content-and-structure

I am about to migrate to SharePoint online, and my manager asked me to generate site map for our intranet.

What is the quick option I have?

I just need a site flow diagram. So that we know what is where.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have Visio installed on your client you can generate the diagram from there.

http://en.share-gate.com/blog/how-to-build-an-inventory-before-sharepoint-migration

Similar issue:

https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/Lync/en-US/bcb22e97-eac3-47e7-9936-57bc59a61400/sharepoint-site-hierarchy-diagram?forum=sharepointgeneral